# Submitting a form with target _blank does not close the new window

Tags: javascript, html

I am submitting an HTML form with target = "_blank", the response is a generated zip file from the server. In chrome, I am navigated to the blank new window and the file is download in positive case (receiving zip file from the server side) but for negative case scenario if due to an exception at server side or max limit increase than in that we are setting a cookie i.e **'downloadAsset**'. In this scenario, the tab is not getting closed in chrome AND In IE 10 the new window (or tab) opens, I am navigated to the blank new window and when the prompt to (Save, open, or cancel) is displayed, it is on the original tab (now hidden from view) and the new window does not close.

HTML Code:

```
<form id="download-form" target="_blank" method="POST" action="/bin/assetsDownload">
  <input id="download-input" type="hidden" name="paths" >
</form> `
```

Javascript Code :

```
var form1 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#download-form'));
var f2 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#download-input'));
        f2.context.setAttribute('value',dPaths);
            form1.submit();
            // window.close();
            var count=0;
            var cookieFunction=function(){
                count++;
            var downloadAssetCookie = $cookies.get("downloadAsset");
                if(count==100 || downloadAssetCookie){
                    var expireTime=new Date();
                    document.cookie = 'downloadAsset=; Path=/; Expires='+expireTime;
                    clearInterval(stopInterval);
                    if(downloadAssetCookie=="4071"){
                        window.close(); // **here window to be close**
                    }
                }
            }
            var stopInterval=setInterval(cookieFunction, 1000);
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                    clearInterval(stopInterval); 
                }, 15000);
```

sample data in dpaths="/ecms/dam/Assets/video/Mobile-BG_750x1110.png,/ecms/dam/Assets/video/Desktop-BG_750x1110.png"

I have tried using fileSaver.js and blob as well but in that case, invalid zip is getting downloaded.
So is there any way to close the window in negative cases for chrome and for all cases in IE

Comment: Could choose a hidden iframe as target instead.

Comment: Did you put a `console.log()` inside the if-clause where you close window, to check if that if-clause is actually executed?

Comment: Also, I'm not entirely sure `window.close()` would close the target-window, and not the source-window

Comment: @myfunkyside yes it is going inside if-clause (already checked that). Thanks :)